# Bluemix Node+Cloudant boilerplate - EOF error

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I've got some issues using the NodeJS+Cloudant boilerplate.
After creating the app from the catalog, I just add the Git and enable the LiveEdit.

After that, tha app starts normally, but every service call breaks the application, including

> app.get('/', routes.index);

Looking at the logs, the only error displayed is the following:

> 2016/03/07 15:51:16 http: proxy error: EOF
>
> scripts/start: line 60:   216 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${NODE_EXECUTABLE} ${NODE_OPTS} ${BOOT_SCRIPT} ${NODE_ARGS}

Additional notes:

- I've been using Bluemix and NodeJs from quite some time now, but I've been getting this problem only for a couple of days
- I don't have any active firewall that drops the connection

Comment: Did you change anything in the package.json file? Is there anything in the logs when pushing the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is an incompatibility when using Node.js+Cloudant boilerplate, LiveEdit mode and Node.js version 4.2.x.

The workaround is to edit you package.json file and change it to use Node.js version 0.12.x:

```
{
  "name": "cloudant_boilerplate_nodejs",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.13.x",
    "ejs": "2.4.x",
    "cloudant": "1.4.x",
    "body-parser": "1.14.x",
    "method-override": "2.3.x",
    "morgan": "1.6.x",
    "errorhandler": "1.4.x",
    "connect-multiparty": "2.0.x"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.x"    
  }
}
```